# How to prove that a function tends to infinity faster than another function

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

$$f(n) = n^3(\log(n))^{10}$$
$$g(n) = n^3.1$$

How do I prove formally that as $n$ goes to infinity, $f(n)$ will always be strictly larger than $g(n)\times c$ where $c$ is some constant.

I have computed the derivatives but I don't know the proper way to prove this.

Comment: `f(n) will always be strictly larger than g(n)×c` Not "*always*", for example $\,f(1)=0 \lt 1 = g(1)\,$. You probably mean "*for large enough n*", in which case use that $\,f(n) / g(n) \to \infty\,$ when $n \to \infty\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does not require calculus. $\log(n)$ is a monotonically increasing function, so for any $n\geq 3$,
$$ n^3 \log(3)^{10} \leq n^3 \log(n)^{10}$$

Given that $e < 3$, we have $1 = \log(e) < \log(3)$, so for any $n\geq 3$,
$$g(n) = n^3 < n^3 \log(3)^{10} \leq n^3 \log(n)^{10} = f(n)$$